# How to get the RESUMEID Value in the var

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch some specific data via a JSON Api, and access the result for the "RESUMEID".

To do this, I get file from contents, and json encode it.

```
$url = '####';

$JSON = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($JSON);
var_dump($data);
```

When I dump the data, It's quite a lot, and I'm not quite sure how to specifically fetch the "RESUMEID" Variable.

Here's how the data looks like -->

```
{
"response":{
      "result":{
         "Candidates":{
            "row":{
               "no":"1",
               "FL":[
                  {
                     "content":"208468000000171001",
                     "val":"RESUMEID"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Not specified",
                     "val":"Modified by"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Yesterday",
                     "val":"Modified time"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"284",
                     "val":"Candidate ID"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Scott",
                     "val":"First name"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Example First Name",
                     "val":"Last name"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"exampleemail@gmail.com",
                     "val":"Email ID"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Beijing",
                     "val":"Current City"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Yesterday",
                     "val":"Created On"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Embed",
                     "val":"Source"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Intermediate",
                     "val":"Read/Type"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Conversational",
                     "val":"Listen/Speak"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"_Resume.doc",
                     "val":"Attach resume",
                     "type":"url",
                     "url":"http://sdsLkRIyw--"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"New",
                     "val":"Resume status"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"2 years",
                     "val":"Time in China"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"-----",
                     "val":"Tell us more about your professional interests in joining ATLAS-China and career goals"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"2011",
                     "val":"Graduation year (undergraduate)"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Marketing",
                     "val":"Desired Industry or ATLAS Role"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Beijing",
                     "val":"Location Preference"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"Yes, &quot;Branding and Digital Marketing Junior Strategist&quot;",
                     "val":"Is this in reference to a particular job?"
                  },
                  {
                     "content":"10,000RMB/month (flexible)",
                     "val":"Salary Range"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "uri":"/ats/private/json/Candidates/getRecords"
   }
}
```

I tried to get the RESUMEID, by calling adding this -->

```
$id = $data->response->result->RESUMEID;
```

but I get nothing. Looking at the var_dump above, what would you write to fetch specifically the content for RESUMEID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>` to get a structured  output of your JSON object.

The tree would look something like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [response] => stdClass Object
        (
            [result] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Candidates] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [row] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [no] => 1
                                    [FL] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [content] => 208XXX
                                                    [val] => RESUMEID
                                                )
```

To retrieve the `RESUMEID` text, you can do:

```
$id = $data->response->result->Candidates->row->FL[0]->val;
```

If you're trying to retrieve the ID (starting with 208), then you'd do:

```
$id = $data->response->result->Candidates->row->FL[0]->val;
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/69328)

Answer (score 0):

You have to [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) your `$data -> response -> result -> Candidates -> row -> FL` array like this:

```
$result = array_filter($data -> response -> result -> Candidates -> row -> FL, function($item){
  return $item -> val === 'RESUMED';
});

echo $result -> content;
```